# Flow of control in Struts 1.2 (Lifecycle)

Tags: java, struts, struts-1, struts-config

Title may sound a little vague but I'll give it a go. I have 2 servlets:

1. **one.java:** Extends the `Action class` forwards the page to success or failure based on the inputs at `index.jsp`
2. **two.java:** Extends the `ActionForm class`, Has getters and setters method

I have 3 jsp files:

1. **index.jsp:** Is the welcome pages and asks for a username combination
2. **success.jsp:** Is called if the combination is correct
3. **failure.jsp:** Is called if the combination is false

I have 2 xml files:

1. **web.xml:** DD
2. **struts-config.xml:** Struts config file

I understand how web.xml works. My only doubt is, which one of the, **one.java /two.java** is called first from the struts.xml?

I tried to debug and found out that the `ActionForm` class i.e `two.java` is called first, then it returns the value to the `Action`i.e `one.java`.

But isn't Action class is supposed to execute first,and then the action form ? I mean This is what MVC architecture follows.

Please explain. Links to a very highly detailed workflow would be really helpful.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is not surprising that `ActionForm` class is called before `Action` - Struts form should be filled with user's data before calling of Struts action method, any of which has 4 parameters:

```
ActionMapping actionMapping,
ActionForm actionForm,
HttpServletRequest request,
HttpServletResponse response
```

Second one - `ActionForm` - should be ready to allow furthest data processing. I've just found [great sequence diagram](http://rollerjm.free.fr/pro/Struts11.html#3) to illustrate all Struts lifecycle stages:

[image]

In short:

1. After getting client's request Struts front-controller calls `RequestProcessor` to find out appropriate action and form using *struts-config.xml*
2. `RequestProcessor` gets Struts form object (or creates it if it doesn't exist), populates with data from request, initiates validation (if exists) and calls appropriate Struts action.
3. Struts action performs all furthers necessary operations.

Comment: @PunjanSudhar, I do not know much about using ExtJS at the backend

Comment: My bad, I would like to add another point. The Actionform isn't called if we are using EXTJS as the FrontEnd(i mistakenly mentioned backend). I think this is because there are already data validation mechanism in extjs. So the form beam needn't be checked. Is that concept correct?

Comment: How do you user ExtJS at frontend? Actually I do not believe that Struts know anything about Ext validation.